# Understandig PHP, multiple terms for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce filter which are written in php.

In this example I like hook into the product tabs and display only a specific tab in a specific category what does its job very well.

```
add_filter( 'wc_tab_manager_product_tabs', 'wc_tab_manager_product_tabs' );
```

function wc_tab_manager_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

```
global $product;

foreach ( $tabs as $tab_name => $tab ) {

    if ( 'my-tab' == $tab_name ) {

        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

        if ( ! in_array( 'Sample Category', $categories ) ) {
            unset( $tabs[ $tab_name ] );
        }
    }
}

return $tabs;
```

}

But what if I need to show it on more than Sample Category? how can I add

I tried with 'Sample Category', 'Sample Category', $categories but it does not work...

and what if I need more than this one my-tab?

Can anybody help me to understand?

Comment: have you tried `!in_array( 'Sample Category', $categories ) && !in_array( 'Other Category', $categories )` ? Is this the kind of stuff you want ?